# npm start how to specify start file other than index.js

Tags: reactjs, server, npm-start

I run create-react-app then switch to directory and run npm start. Just wondering how I would specify a different file than index.js to start on the server

Here's my package.json file:

```
{
 "name": "todo",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "react": "^16.2.0",
   "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
   "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
 },
 "scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 }
}
```

I tried changing:

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
```

to

```
"start": "node index.js",  or  "start": "node ./src/index.js",
```

but those don't work

Answer (score 2):

For now there is no argument for running different file.js in react. so you need to eject your react application by command

```
npm run eject
```

By running this you will have full control in your project. Then you need to modify some code in your config/paths.js

```
module.exports = {
  dotenv: resolveApp('.env'),
  appPath: resolveApp('.'),
  appBuild: resolveApp(buildPath),
  appPublic: resolveApp('public'),
  appHtml: resolveApp('public/index.html'),
  //appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/index'),
  appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/'+ process.argv[process.argv.length-1]),
  appPackageJson: resolveApp('package.json'),
  appSrc: resolveApp('src'),
  appTsConfig: resolveApp('tsconfig.json'),
  appJsConfig: resolveApp('jsconfig.json'),
  yarnLockFile: resolveApp('yarn.lock'),
  testsSetup: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/setupTests'),
  proxySetup: resolveApp('src/setupProxy.js'),
  appNodeModules: resolveApp('node_modules'),
  swSrc: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/service-worker'),
  publicUrlOrPath,
};
```

Take a note on these lines:

```
//appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/index'),
appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/'+ process.argv[process.argv.length-1]),
```

src/index mean npm start will run your application with src/index.js. So by changing the code you can pass argument with new file name for example

```
npm start -- foo
```

So your application will run with new file in src/foo.js.
Normaly your argument is last item. If code is not working you can try to print all arguments by

```
// print process.argv
process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
  console.log(index + ': ' + val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Find and edit *package.json* file. For example:

```
{
  "name": "build",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node different-file.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Add the error when you launch node new-file.js so that I can help you

Comment: @Ignacio I also got the issue.

Comment: Which is the error that it returns? I've used `"scripts": {"start": "node server.js"}` in all projects without problems