# How to run one 'npm start' for two different folders in my project directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-scripts

I would like to run one `npm start` command to run both my frontend folder and backend folder. Currently, I have to navigate inside each folder and individually run the command on both to see my app open on the localhost. I have looked into the package 'concurrently' but am having some trouble implementing it in my package.json file.
Here is my package.json file for my frontend folder:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "set HOST = 'http://localhost' && set PORT=8000 && react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"postbuild": "react-snap"
```

}

I have tried using this bit to run the backend once I run npm start on the frontend however it did not work:

```
"start": "set HOST = 'http://localhost' && set PORT=8000 && ../backend/ start & react-scripts start"
```

**Edit**:
Still having some troubles after reattempting.

Here are my scripts from my package.json files

**Frontend folder**

```
"scripts": {
"start": "set HOST = 'http://localhost' && set PORT=8000 && react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "jest",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"postbuild": "react-snap"
},
```

**Backend Folder**

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node ./bin/www"
},
```

The front end is written in React and the backend in Node. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just use 1 package.json for both client and server?

Comment: How could I do that? Move it into either frontend/backend, or move it outside into the project directory?

Comment: Have a single root directory e.g. /project which has your package.json and node_modules which have any dependencies for both client and server, and a /client and /server folder in /project.

Comment: Both my client and server folders have their own node_modules and package.json ...

Comment: Then merge your dependencies into a single package.json which can be found in your package.json files. Then do a fresh `npm i` in /project

Comment: If you are using macos try the Keyboard Maestro. My favorite app ever.

Comment: I think the solution is similar to what I answered in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737535/npm-start-how-to-specify-start-file-other-than-index-js/70029988#70029988

Answer (score 10):

Install concurrently:

```
npm i concurrently --save-dev
```

Now go to your package.json and add this:

```
"start": "node index.js",
"client": "npm run start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run start\" \"npm run client\""
```

(assuming your client folder contains the front-end server)

then, if you wanna run both servers, just type npm run dev and be happy

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same issue but it is resolved now. Let's say the server is in the 'Backend' folder and the frontend is in the 'client' folder.

then scripts in server-side package.json should be like:

```
"scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "cd ../ && npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

and client-side package.json is like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

then 'npm run dev' runs concurrntly both the server

Answer (score 3):

The 'concurrently' package can do this

```
npm i concurrently --save-dev
```

Then set up `npm run dev` to do

```
"dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run start-watch\" \"npm run wp-server\""
```

Another option is to do (Running in Windows CMD):

```
"dev": "start npm run start-watch && start npm run wp-server"
```